# How do I avoid adding duplicate collections in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorboard

Tensorflow beginner here.

I have a piece of code that does training and validation (together) on a set of images. Every so often, in the training loop, I perform a validation and obtain the loss from a validation dataset. I summarize the results and use tensorboard to view my visualization.

My problem is, I'm counting my loss twice and I shouldn't be. My code will make it clear what is happening

Get some images that are already split into training and validation sets, also build the neural net:

```
        images, labels = (
            self._input_pipeline(filenames, self.model_config.BATCH_SIZE))
        v_images, v_labels = (
            self._input_pipeline(v_filenames, self.model_config.BATCH_SIZE))
        logits = self.build_nets(images)
        tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
        v_logits = self.build_nets(v_images)
```

Set the loss function:

```
        _ = self.set_loss(logits, labels)
        validation_step = self.set_loss(v_logits, v_labels)
```

This is what set_loss looks like:

```
def set_loss(self, y, y_):
    cross_entropy_sum = (
                tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=y_)))
    tf.add_to_collection('cross_entropy_loss', cross_entropy_sum)
    return tf.losses.get_losses()
```

The problem that is happening is that cross_entropy_loss is added twice to the collection thereby giving me a 2x output of the cross entropy loss

The collection 'cross_entropy_loss' is used back in the main routine to compute the cross_entropy_total:

```
        get_cross_entropy = tf.get_collection('cross_entropy_loss')
        cross_entropy_total = tf.add_n(get_cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy_loss_across_all_gpus')
        tf.summary.scalar("cross entropy loss", cross_entropy_total)
```

A single summary op generates the summary:

```
        summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
```

The training step looks like this:

```
        train_step = (
            tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(model_config.INITIAL_LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cross_entropy_total))
```

Here is the final piece, running the training piece and the validation pieces and writing out the summary

```
                _, cross_entropy = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy_total])
                if step % self.model_config.SUMMARY_EVERY == 0:
                    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
                    summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
                    #validation
                    _, cross_entropy = sess.run([validation_step, cross_entropy_total])
                    v_summary_str = sess.run(summary_op)
                    v_summary_writer.add_summary(v_summary_str, step)
```

So can someone help me how to avoid counting cross_entropy_total twice?
For example if the loss without performing the validation is 100, if I plug in the validation pieces shown above it becomes 200

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: I am wondering why you should add the validation loss to the cross_entropy_loss collection and then update the weights by it. If the step is for validation the loss should not be skipped to be added to the collection which only contains training losses.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, people feed training and validation data via the `feed_dict` argument to `sess.run`. This way, the "graph" does not depend on the dataset section.

Also, it's not clear to me why you even need to use "collections" here. You can just feed `cross_entropy_sum = tf.reduce_sum ...` to `minimize`.

Comment: @wrecktangle https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners (Crtl-F feed_dict)

Comment: Also I'd like to minimize cross_entropy_total which is the cross_entropy_sum across multiple gpu's, so how can I do that without collections?